# boost this_thread interruption_point not captured

Tags: c++, boost-asio

When running in debug mode, this crashes when throwing an interruption error:

How to interrupt the thread pool, and how to properly capture the interruption (and where? in the dispatched job, or in the CancelAll?)
it doesn't crash if there are no interruption point, but the thread do not get interrupted. When I put interruption point, it crashes when throwing an interruption error.

```
class ThreadAsioPool
{
public:
  ThreadAsioPool(const std::size_t nb_threads);
  virtual ~ThreadAsioPool() { CancelAll(); }

  void CancelAll();
  void AddJob(Wrapcontainer &wrap);

protected:
  static void job(Wrapcontainer wrap);
  void AddThread() {m_threadgroup.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io)); }
private:
  std::size_t nbThreads;
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  boost::thread_group m_threadgroup;
  boost::asio::io_service::work *work;
};

ThreadAsioPool::ThreadAsioPool(const std::size_t nb_threads): nbThreads(nb_threads)
{
  work = new boost::asio::io_service::work(io);//will keep io busy so it won't stop
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nbThreads; ++i)
    AddThread();
}
void ThreadAsioPool::AddJob(Wrapcontainer &wrap)
{
  //after a CancelAll, the m_threadgroup would be empty, so add more thread if needed
  if (m_threadgroup.size() < nbThreads )
    AddThread();

  io.post(boost::bind(&ThreadAsioPool::job,wrap));
  io.reset();
  io.poll();
}
void ThreadAsioPool::CancelAll()
{
  try{
    io.stop();//not sure that's necessary to stop the queue from processing
    m_threadgroup.interrupt_all(); //this to empty the queue
    m_threadgroup.join_all();//I assume after this line that the m_threadgroup is empty
  }
  catch(boost::thread_interrupted const& e){
    int i=0;//so I can put a breakpoint to see if it gets there, and it doesn't
    i=1;
  }
  catch(std::exception const& e){
    int i=0;//doesn't get here either
    i=2;
  }
  catch(...){
    int i=0;//doesn't get here either
    i=3;
  }

}
void ThreadAsioPool::job(Wrapcontainer wrap)
{

  try{
    boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
    ...some work..
    boost::this_thread::interruption_point(); //inserting few interruption point between heavy task
    ...some work..
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50)); //different type of breakpoint see if it makes a difference
    ...some work..
    boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
  }//try
  catch(boost::thread_interrupted& e){
    int i=0;//so I can put a breakpoint to see if it gets there, and it doesn't
    i=1;
  }
  catch(std::exception const& e){
    int i=0;//doesn't get here either
    i=2;
  }
  catch(...){
    int i=0;//doesn't get here either
    i=3;
  }


}

void main()
{
  ThreadAsioPool threadpool(3);

  //add 50 jobs in the queue
  for (int i=0;i<50;i++){
    Wrapcontainer itemdata;//just a class to contain data for the job
    ... fill up 'itemdata' with required data for the job

    threadpool.AddJob(itemdata);//feed a job
  }
  threadpool.CancelAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `AddJob` you already do all the work. You're not queuing anything and execution is sequential: **[Simple Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6863002bea321a7a)**

```
Job Job 1 done main.cpp
2 done main.cpp
Job 3 done main.cpp
Job 4 done main.cpp
Job 5 done main.cpp
Job 6 done main.cpp
Job 7 done main.cpp
Job 8 done main.cpp
Job 9 done main.cpp
Job 10 done main.cpp
Canceling
```

Fix it by **not** doing `reset()` and `poll()` (you already have the workers doing `run()`, right?).

Sample (in a minute):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31d7cd3f87639828)</kbd>**

> This sample leaves "resetting" the thread pool/queue after cancelling as an exercise to the reader. Consider **KISS** though: you can always make the `ThreadAsioPool` cancel during destruction, and just create a new instance for any more work.
>
> This would have exactly the desired behaviour with no complexity in coding.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

struct Wrapcontainer {
    int id = id_gen();
  private:
    static int id_gen() {
        static int seed = 0;
        return ++seed;
    }
};

class ThreadAsioPool {
  public:
    ThreadAsioPool(const std::size_t nb_threads);
    virtual ~ThreadAsioPool() { CancelAll(); }

    void CancelAll();
    void AddJob(Wrapcontainer &wrap);

  protected:
    static void job(Wrapcontainer wrap);
    void AddThread() { m_threadgroup.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io)); }

  private:
    std::size_t nbThreads;
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::thread_group m_threadgroup;
    boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work;
};

ThreadAsioPool::ThreadAsioPool(const std::size_t nb_threads) 
    : nbThreads(nb_threads), io(), 
      work(boost::asio::io_service::work(io))
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nbThreads; ++i)
        AddThread();
}

void ThreadAsioPool::AddJob(Wrapcontainer &wrap) {
    // after a CancelAll, the m_threadgroup would be empty, so add more thread if needed
    if (m_threadgroup.size() < nbThreads)
        AddThread();

    io.post(boost::bind(&ThreadAsioPool::job, wrap));
}

void ThreadAsioPool::CancelAll() {
    try {
        work.reset();
        io.stop(); // not sure that's necessary to stop the queue from processing
        m_threadgroup.interrupt_all(); // this to empty the queue
        m_threadgroup.join_all(); // I assume after this line that the m_threadgroup is empty
    } catch (boost::thread_interrupted const &e) {
        std::cout << "CAUGHT " + std::to_string(__LINE__) << "\n";
    } catch (std::exception const &e) {
        std::cout << "CAUGHT" + std::to_string(__LINE__) << "\n";
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "CAUGHT " + std::to_string(__LINE__) << "\n";
    }
}
void ThreadAsioPool::job(Wrapcontainer wrap) {
    try {
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point(); // inserting few interruption point between heavy task
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50)); // different type of breakpoint see if it makes a difference
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        std::cout << "Job " << wrap.id << " done " + std::to_string(__LINE__) << "\n";
    } // try
    catch (boost::thread_interrupted &e) {
        std::cout << "CAUGHT " + std::to_string(__LINE__) << "\n";
    } catch (std::exception const &e) {
        std::cout << "CAUGHT " + std::to_string(__LINE__) << "\n";
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "CAUGHT " + std::to_string(__LINE__) << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    ThreadAsioPool threadpool(3);

    // add 50 jobs in the queue
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        Wrapcontainer itemdata; // just a class to contain data for the job
        //... fill up 'itemdata' with required data for the job
        threadpool.AddJob(itemdata);//feed a job
    }
    std::cout << "Canceling\n";

    threadpool.CancelAll();
}
```

Prints

```
Canceling
CAUGHT 71
CAUGHT 71
CAUGHT 71
```

**note** Catching the interrupted exception in `CancelAllJobs` is a bit funny (unless you wanted to protect against leaking the exception when it's called from within a pooled thread).

Comment: I added the mentioned edits (declaring 'work' as:
    boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work;)
and init the class with nbThreads(nb_threads), io(), work(boost::asio::io_service::work(io)). 
The AddJob does not have io.poll() neither io.reset()
and the CancelAll does contain the work.reset().
I did try with and without io.stop() as well. I get the same crash as originally. It is throwing the interruption exception but it is not catching it. The debugger points to thread.cpp line 715:
    throw thread_interrupted();

Comment: Are dynamic libraries involved? Did you rebuild everything with the same compiler flags?

Comment: it's linked with static library. I precompiled boost thread and link against libboost_thread-mgw48-mt-d-1_57.a (for the debug). The linker also has -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ (by the way compiler and linker options were the same as originally posted, no changes there)

Comment: Mmm. Is it an option to try isolated? You can see it works in the Live-On-Coliru sample. Maybe you can change that to use static linking and see whether that introduces it. I'm suspecting ODR violations/incompatible name manglings (meaning: you're catching a different type than is thrown)

Comment: Is there a way to see what is thrown before it crashes? (though the debugger and the call stack seem to indicate that it is throwing thread_interrupted(); )

Comment: So. It appears all you have to do is open your eyes/trust the tools to see what is thrown :) (`gdb` has `catch throw` command)

Comment: the last line on the call stack is __cxa_throw()